# How do i switch Appbar title and child content with state-management in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, appbar

I have a problem i have been struggling to get done for a day now

I want to dynamically switch appbar from this :

[image: Initial]

to this :

[image: Final]

when a button is pressed.
The button is situated in the scaffold bottomNavigationBar of the first appbar widget.

I will give the code snippet of this particular widget.

I tried creating an entirely different widget and set the button `onTap` function to route to the new widget created.

This is not a suitable solution for me as i wish to just change state of the appbar as to avoid the weird transition when changing pages.

Also please note that the second image has a leading button that would enable the user to go back to the previous appbar.

How do i achieve this?

THIS IS THE CODE SNIPPET

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class CustomersView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<CustomersView> createState() => _CustomersViewState();
}

class _CustomersViewState extends State<CustomersView> {
  List<String> items = [
    "All",
    "Inactive",
    "One time",
    "Loyal",
    "Active",
  ];
  int current = 0;

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> get dropdownItems {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> menuItems = [
      DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(
            "Today",
          ),
          value: "Today"),
    ];
    return menuItems;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final controller = Get.put(EServicesController());
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 60,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          "Customers".tr,
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              color: Color(0xff000000),
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),
        actions: [
          SearchButtonWidget(),
          SettingsButtonWidget(),
        ],
        centerTitle: false,
        elevation: 0,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leadingWidth: 15,
        // leading: new IconButton(
        //   icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Color(0xff3498DB)),
        //   onPressed: () => {Get.back()},
        // ),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () async {
          // Get.find<LaravelApiClient>().forceRefresh();
          // await controller.refreshNotifications(showMessage: true);
          // Get.find<LaravelApiClient>().unForceRefresh();
        },
        child: ListView(
          primary: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            mainHeader(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            CustomersCategoriesBuilder(current: current),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      //floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,

      bottomNavigationBar: current == 0 ? SizedBox() : MessageCustomersButton(),
    );
  }

//Button that controls the appbar state
class MessageCustomersButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessageCustomersButton({
    Key key,
    this.value = false,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final bool value;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: FadeInDown(
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
            //this is the new page route ( unsatisfied approach )
              Get.toNamed(Routes.MESSAGE_CUSTOMERS);
            },
            color: Color(0xff34495E),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.18),
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
            minWidth: double.infinity,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.chat,
                  size: 18,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Message Customers',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the widget for AppBar only and handle the different states of AppBar there only by passing a flag like `isSecondStyleAppBar` then in your CustomersView widget, handle the flag using `setState`

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isSecondStyleAppBar;
  const CustomAppBar(this.isSecondStyleAppBar, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const AppBar();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for this response, but please can you clarify me on how i can manage my state in the said AppBar widget? I am not really advanced in flutter and i might have problems too doing that :(

Comment: Let's say how we control the color of container, by passing the color in the argument right? In the same way you can pass lets say isSecondStyleAppBar properties in your customAppBar Widget. 
Managing state is simple, you declare a variable and then change its value and call setState to update the UI

Comment: let me go face it, i'll let you know when i'm done.

Comment: How do i change the state of the appbars when the button is pressed? That is my only problem now sir

Comment: declare a flag variable like
`bool changeAppBar = false`
and in button press do
`setState((){changeAppBar = !changeAppBar;});`